# how can i use AsyncStorage data Everywhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am using the saga library. And tokens are stored in AsyncStorage.
What I want is to freely use the token obtained from AsyncStorage in the loadUserPosts function or in loadPosts.
In this case, where should async be added and how do I fix the code?

this is my code

```
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenstore');

    function* loadUserPosts(action) {
      try {
        console.log(token)
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
      }
    }

    function* loadPosts(action) {
      try {
        console.log(token)
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POSTS_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
    }




    function* watchLoadPost() {
      yield takeLatest(LOAD_POST_REQUEST, loadPosts);
    }

    function* watchLoadUserPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, LOAD_USER_POSTS_REQUEST, loadUserPosts);
    }

    export default function* postSaga() {
      yield all([

        fork(watchLoadPosts),
        fork(watchLoadUserPosts),
      ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and yield you async result. You might not even need `async` becuase generator function will yield until it gets a result.

```
function* loadUserPosts(action) {
  try {
    const token = yield AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenstore');
    console.log(token)
    yield put(LOAD_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS(token));
  } catch (err) {
  }
```